# SQL/Oracle 10g - Issue with triggers

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having an issue with SQL/Oracle 10g when it comes to create a statement level trigger. What I'm trying to achieve with this trigger is to delete a practical class when enrollment of students is < 5. Below is what I've written:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER delete_prac
AFTER UPDATE ON studEnrol
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM pracList
   WHERE Practical IN (
   SELECT Practical
   FROM studEnrol
   GROUP BY Practical
   HAVING COUNT(Practical) < 5);
END delete_prac;
```

The error I'm getting however is:

```
ORA-04091: pracList table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
```

I've looked into this error and the suggestions that arose were to include the :new and :old keywords, but I don't know how I would do that.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks.

EDIT: Forgot to add which table was mutating, its the pracList table
EDIT2: Changed it to a statement level trigger and the mutating table still occurs with pracList

Comment: do you have another triggers on pracList?

Comment: show ddl on tables: pracList, studEnrol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably occurs as Florin Ghita suggests because you have a trigger on `praclist`. When you update `studenrol` you then try to delete from `praclist`. This act fires another trigger, which causes your problem. This error is raised in order to provide a read consistent view of the data. As [Tom Kyte says](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:9579487119866) this error could be indicative of a flaw in your schema or logic, and you should reconsider one or both.

Also, and generally speaking, full table scans, which is what you're doing, in a trigger are *A Bad Idea <sup>TM</sup>*. Depending on the size of the table you might end up spending 1 second or 2 hours on each and every update on `studlist`, which is far from optimal.

Without knowing your schema or what the trigger on `praclist` does it's difficult to be certain, however, in your case, there seems to be an *"out"*. Drop this trigger entirely; there is no need for it.

Create a [materialized view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6002.htm) on `praclist` to provide you the data you need. It doesn't make sense anyway to be constantly deleting and inserting values into `praclist` when you can just have a view that keeps the information in here constantly up-to-date. The following query should do it:

```
select p.*
  from praclist p
  join ( select practical
           from studenrol
          group by practical
         having count(*) >= 5 ) s
    on p.practical = s.practical
```

Incidentally, your current trigger doesn't allow for an insert into `praclist` if the number of students enrolled suddenly becomes enough for a practical to take place. A materialized view takes care of this problem as well as the mutating table error.

Answer (score 1):

remove `FOR EACH ROW`

Then your trigger will run only once after update rows, and the table will not be mutating.

Comment: Doesn't work. I tried changing a students enrollment in the studEnrol table from one practical to another and the error still occurs. For example, 5 students were enrolled in physics, then I edit one student who was doing physics to do maths and the trigger should delete the practical from the praclist.